# Swift and Spritekit won't run on device running iOS 7.1

Tags: sprite-kit, swift, xcode6

I'm getting a really weird warning when I try to run my Swift project on my device, using Xcode 6.

The device is running iOS 7.1, and my mac is running Mavericks.

I have written a little game in Swift and SpriteKit, and it works in Simulator, but when I try to run it on my device, I get a warning, and my device only shows a black background.

I get the same result when trying to run a fresh SpriteKit project. But if I run a fresh Single Page Application using Swift, it runs normally.

This is the warning I get:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: add an exception breakpoint to see if that reveals more info

Comment: I have the same problem. Seems like the images are not loaded, and scene size is messed up. I could only load images using atlas.

Comment: I had similar problem. And setting deployment target to 8.0 fixed error. So I think unarchiving SKScene from *.sks file is not supported before 8.0. Do you know any documents say that unarchiving is supported on iOS 7.x?

Answer (score 14):

I also got this crash and, comparing to the 7.1.1 SDK SpriteKit game template, it appears to be related to loading the scene from an *.sks* file.

I changed it to use a different initializer like this:

```
let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
```

After that, the template project is not crashing anymore on my iPad mini with iOS 7.1.1. However, the plane sprites don't get rendered. You can see the node count (on the bottom right corner) go up with each tap, but the sprites aren't visible. The "Hello, World!" label shows fine, though...

Comment: worked great thanks Mariano! if anyone wants a fixed version of the template file here it is https://gist.github.com/icodeforlove/abed9fd0b1c43cc14ba3

Comment: Guys, thanks for the solution and ready to use template. Works like a charm.

Comment: Does anyone has found a solution for the sprite to render in the template?

Answer (score 2):

Same behaviour here: default generated SpriteKit game was crashing. Now with the XCode 6 final, it all seems to work just fine, but try to add a particle emitter, and you back to XCode crashing hell. XCode keeps crashing on any particle emitter file saved as .sks file. I found that this is a known bug in XCode 6, that seems to be fixed only in 6.1 beta. See: [Can't open particle SKS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830436/cant-open-particle-sks-files)

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. Have you found any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem too, with me it was crashing on the `self.addChild(myLabel)` on the default scene that loads (the one with Chalkduster "Hello, World!" and spaceships spinning on touch, I think it's called GameScene by default).

Comment out the `self.addChild(myLabel)` in GameScene and see if that stops the crashes. As a temporary solution I just made the `viewDidLoad` method load up another scene straight away and the new scene acts as you'd expect. It seems like it's something on Apples end of things, xCode6 is only in beta after all.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with the latest **Xcode 6 beta 4**. There are still some bugs, but the basic SpriteKit template is now working fine.