# node.physicsBody.joints downcasting error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsjoint

The following code gives an error - it appears the physics joints array have the class PKPhysicsJoint. Anyone have any ideas how I can iterate through the joints in Swift?

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/joints) does say that physicsBody.joints should return an array of SKPhysicsJoint.

```
import SpriteKit

let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
let nodeA = SKNode()
let nodeB = SKNode()

nodeA.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
nodeB.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)

scene.addChild(nodeA)
scene.addChild(nodeB)

let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(nodeA.physicsBody, bodyB: nodeB.physicsBody, anchor: CGPointZero)
scene.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)

for joint in nodeA.physicsBody!.joints as [SKPhysicsJoint] {
  // do something else here
}
```

gives error:

```
Execution was interrupted. reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION...
```

Comment: Try this: `for joint in nodeA.physicsBody!.joints { .. }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update***: This *was* a bug, and it's fixed in iOS 9 / OS X 10.11 — the code in the question just works now.

Leaving original answer text for posterity / folks using older SDKs / etc.

---

This looks like a bug — [you should file it](http://bugreport.apple.com). Whether it should be considered a SpriteKit bug or a Swift bug is hard to say, but that's Apple's problem, not yours. :)

The problem is clear if you paste your code into a playground — your `joint` is actually a `PKPhysicsJointWeld` behind the scenes. That's some internal class that should be an implementation detail. In ObjC that's no problem, because casting in C is just a matter of telling the compiler, "trust me, this pointer is really an `SKPhysicsJoint`, so let me call physics joint methods (and nothing else) on it and and no one will be the wiser". Casting in Swift requires that there be a type hierarchy relationship between the casted types — and `PKPhysicsJointWeld` is not a subtype/subclass of `SKPhysicsJoint`, so the cast fails.

You can work around this issue by avoiding the cast to `[SKPhysicsJoint]`:

```
for joint in nodeA.physicsBody!.joints {
    // do something else here
}
```

With this, you lose some type safety — `joint` is an `AnyObject`, so like ObjC's `id` type the compiler lets you call any method on it. (And it may fail at runtime if that object doesn't implement the method.) But at least it runs.

A further workaround: inside the loop, you can cast `joint` to `SKPhysicsJoint`. But since that cast is across the type hierarchy, you have to use `unsafeBitCast`:

```
for joint in nodeA.physicsBody!.joints {
    let skJoint = unsafeBitCast(joint, SKPhysicsJoint.self)
    // do stuff with skJoint
}
```

This gets you back a little bit of compile-time type "safety", in that thereafter the compiler will require anything you do with `skJoint` to be compatible with `SKPhysicsJoint`, but it's still inherently unsafe in that it depends on some hand-waving around runtime types that may not always hold. And you have to `unsafeBitCast` again to get to a particular joint subclass, without knowing which subclass it might be. (Again, [this would be a good time to file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).)

---

(You might notice from pasting into a playground that `physicsWorld` is of an internal class, too: `PKPhysicsWorld`. So why doesn't that fail, too? When you use the `physicsWorld` property, all the type casting happens on the ObjC side, and Swift trusts whatever ObjC tells it. When you deal with the `joints` array, though, you have to do a type cast on the Swift side, and Swift is much more strict about type checking.)