# Swift convenience initializer extension for SKPhysicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-extensions

```
extension SKPhysicsBody {

    /// anchorPoint version of init(rectangleOfSize:center:)
    convenience init(rectangleOfSize s: CGSize, withAnchorPoint anchorPoint: CGPoint) {
        var center = CGPoint()
        center.x = (s.width / 2) - ( s.width * anchorPoint.x)
        center.y = (s.height / 2 ) - ( s.height * anchorPoint.y)
        self.init(rectangleOfSize: s, center: center)
    }

}
```

I got this error on runtime

```
-[PKPhysicsBody initWithRectangleOfSize:withAnchorPoint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b03c4fff0

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PKPhysicsBody initWithRectangleOfSize:withAnchorPoint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9b03c4fff0'
```

This is how I call in code

```
// redBox is a typical SKSpriteNode()
redBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: redBox.frame.size, withAnchorPoint: redBox.anchorPoint)
```

I basically want to extend the `SKPhysicsBody` class  to provide a convenience initializer to its factory method

Comment: How are you calling the initializer?

Comment: `redBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: redBox.frame.size, withAnchorPoint: redBox.anchorPoint)`

Comment: my current workaround is using factory method `SKPhysicsBody.bodyWithRectangleOfSize(:withAnchorPoint:)` to return a physics body. This totally feel not swift-ty, as all obj-c factory is map nicely to respective init method.

Comment: Seems that SKPhysicsBody is a cluster class and it's `alloc` method returns a private `PKPhysicsBody` instance that doesn't have the `init` just added.

Comment: I read some other SpriteKit project with SKPhysicsBody extension to conveniently create physic body, they mostly use a class method create a body and return it, is this the only neat way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Cristik guessed in the comments, this is the same root problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28501832/957768) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25004232/957768): the public `SKPhysicsBody` class is a convenience interface for the private `PKPhysicsBody` class that provides its implementation.

In the past, this approach relied heavily on the ["duck typing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) behavior of Objective-C — as long as `ClassA` responds to all the same selectors as `ClassB`, you can call any of those selectors on a pointer whose static type (the type declared to the compiler in source code) is `ClassB`, even if the actual object at run time is really an instance of `ClassA`.

Swift is stricter about runtime type correctness than ObjC, so "duck typing" alone is not enough. Since iOS 9 / OS X 10.11, SpriteKit has some workarounds that allow `PKPhysicsBody` instances to better pretend to be `SKPhysicsBody` instances.

But those don't cover all cases — in particular, it doesn't catch (ObjC) `[SKPhysicsBody alloc]` returning a `PKPhysicsBody` instance, which means any attempt to add initializers to `SKPhysicsBody` in Swift will fail. (Because the ObjC `alloc`/`init` process is reduced to one initializer call in Swift.)

I'd consider this a bug and recommend [filing it with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com).

---

Edit/update: And until that bug gets fixed (it's been a year and some now), the workaround is to make your convenience "initializer" into a class method instead. (Or a global function if you must, but... ewww.)